# CSS loads before Bootstrap, causing elements to be messed

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have a bootstrap navbar that seemed to work perfect on Adobe Dreamweaver. When I uploaded the files to my server today, I noticed something really annoying:

if you click on http://www.creatyvetest.co.nf you will see that on first/second load, the whole bootstrap navbar is messed up.

On third load, it seems to all come together perfectly again. What is happening? It seems like bootstrap is loading after CSS?

Navbar loads like this:
[What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcJ8g.png)

Navbar should look like this:
[What it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kA1wT.png)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you have any screenshots of what the navigation should look like? It hasn't changed since I first loaded it. Also, it's a good idea to try and load as little JavaScript files as possible in the head and leave the rest for the end of the file, this way you can save your loading times because the weighty JavaScript is loaded last.

Comment: Hi @lewisnewson,

I just uploaded them in the post, thanks. Also, I think I need those js files because I have some js stuff going on (this website is just a simplified mock up)